# JAVA setColor in paintComponent stays blank

Tags: java

I'm trying to change the background of my little programm as soon as someone hits space (32). It just won't work and I have been trying different things and everything I could find on the internet like putting the `g.setColor(Color.BLUE);`
at the beginning of the `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`block.

Here I got the following code.
My Screen.java

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable{

Thread thread = new Thread(this);
Frame frame;

private int fps = 0; 
public int scene = 0;
public boolean running = false;

public Screen(Frame frame){
    this.frame = frame;
    this.frame.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler(this));
    thread.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    super.paint(g);
    g.clearRect(0, 0, this.frame.getWidth(),this.frame.getHeight());
    g.drawString(fps + "", 10, 10);

    if (scene == 0) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (scene == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
    }
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}


public void run() {
   System.out.println("[Success] Frame Created!");

   long lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
   int frames = 0;

   running = true;
   scene = 0;

   while(running){
       repaint();
       frames++;

       if(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 >= lastFrame){
           fps = frames;
           frames = 0;
           lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
       }

       try {
           Thread.sleep(2);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   System.exit(0);
   }

    public class KeyTyped{
    public void keySPACE() {
        scene = 1;
    }
    public void keyESC(){
        running = false;
    }


   }
  }

   KeyHandler.java

 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

 public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {

public Screen screen;
public Screen.KeyTyped keyTyped;

public KeyHandler(Screen screen){
    this.screen = screen;
    this.keyTyped = this.screen.new KeyTyped();

  }

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    System.out.println(keyCode);

    if(keyCode == 27){
        this.keyTyped.keyESC();
    }        
    if(keyCode == 32){
        this.keyTyped.keySPACE();
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

   }    
}
```

I don't know why the code isn't in one block. Seems like I'm doing something wrong with it?

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  what happens instead?  are there any messages or stack traces on your console?  How have you tried to diagnose the problem (adding random code from the internet into your program generally won't work)?

Comment: Oh damn, I have been reading this list about the what a good post is on stackoverflow just before I posted this and now I notice I forgot to describe half of the problem.

The background just stays blank like the normal start background(Im more or less colorblind and see only little changes, so I cant tell you which color the background exactly got, but its not blue or green)

I tried to change the code, place it somewhere else I used to read different ways of doing in on the internet. Added the super.paintComponent etc..

There are no messages, sadly.

Comment: no worries, and glad you're taking the time to read the list!  you're off to a better start than a lot of people.  I'd pay special attention to the parts that mention [SSCCEs](http://sscce.org/) - often times, during the process of creating one to include in your question, you find yourself realizing what the problem is all on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use [InputMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html) / ActionMap instead of a KeyListener
2. You need to make sure the JComponent is set to isFocusable(true), and you do component.requestFocus() when first shown to make sure that your action will trigger.

Comment: You don't need step 2 if you use step 1, that is the benefit of using `Key Bindings`. The component doesn't have to have focus. I would start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 0):

please do the corrections:
1. use `JFrame` instead of `Frame`
2. implemement `paintComponent` like this:

```
    g.clearRect(0, 0, this.frame.getWidth(),this.frame.getHeight());
    if (scene == 0) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (scene == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
    }
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(fps + "", 10, 10);
```

3. make sure `Screen` is added `JFrame`
4. make sure to issue `setVisible(true)` on `JFrame`